# "Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses" error while parsing BBCode text with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, text-parsing, bbcode

I get an error saying "Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 11" while trying to parse BBCode with an array of regex patterns.

I have no idea what `offset 11` means and I've checked all my parentheses and there are no unclosed sets.

Here's my code:

```
function bbParse($string) {
    $codes = array(
        '/\[b\](.+?)\[\/b\]/' => '<b>$1</b>', 
        '/\[h2\](.+?)\[\/h2\]/' => '<h2>$1</h2>', 
        '/\[h3\](.+?)\[\/h3\]/' => '<h3>$1</h3>', 
        '/\[p\](.+?)\[\/p\]/' => '<p>$1</p>', 
        '/\[quote\](.+?)\[\/quote\]/' => '<blockquote>$1</blockquote>', 
        '/\[img\](.+?)\[\/img\]/' => '<img src=\'$1\' alt=\'Image Not Available\'>',
        '/\[url=\(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/' => '<a href=\'$1\'>$2</a>'
    );
    
        
    $string = preg_replace(array_keys($codes), array_values($codes), $string);

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: This is an off-topic: typo question.  You have escaped the opening parenthesis in the last array element's key.  The attempt to capture the opening `url` tag's value is not coded as intended because the capture group is not opened properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/\[url=\(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/`

The first grouping paren in this regex is escaped, making it a literal parenthesis character. The closing one therefore has no matching opening paren. You need to remove the `\` preceding the first parenthesis, making it thus:

`/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the very last entry is the culprit.  The opening parent is escaped with a backslash, which might not be what you are wanting.

Answer (score 1):

Here you escape a `(`, so it fails because there is no `(` to the next `)`:

```
'/\[url=\(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/' => '<a href=\'$1\'>$2</a>'
```